# Как создать кортеж содержащий списки, из словаря в Python?

Tags: python, словари, tuple

есть словарь с такой структурой:

```
dict = {
    'x1[0]': ['aaa', '000'],
    'x1[1]': ['bbb', '111'],
    'x1[2]': ['ccc', '222'],
    'x1[3]': ['ddd', '333'],
    'x1[4]': ['eee', '444'],
}
```

нужно создать такого вида кортеж:

```
markup = ([
    [Button.inline('aaa', query='x1[0]', same_peer = True), Button.inline('bbb', query='x1[1]', same_peer = True)],
    [Button.inline('ccc', query='x1[2]', same_peer = True), Button.inline('ddd', query='x1[3]', same_peer = True)],
    [Button.inline('eee', query='x1[4]', same_peer = True)]
])
```

Как это сделать в Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, например как-то так:

```
dict_list = [Button.inline(dict[k][0], query=k, same_peer = True) for k in dict]
markup = ([dict_list[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(dict_list), 2)],)
```

Comment: Этот ответ помог, спасибо! единственное убрал запятую перед последней круглой скобкой, она вызывала ошибку в дальнейшем у меня в коде: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute

Comment: @Brumo Ну тогда там и кортежа никакого не будет. Останется только список списков. Хотя если это кнопки для бота Телеграма, то там список списков и нужен.

Comment: Можно даже круглые скобки убрать. Без запятой они в данном случае никакой смысловой нагрузки не несут.

Comment: да, для бота, по поводу запятой немного непонятно(почему без нее кортеж становится списком списков), я только начал изучать python. Искал по крупицам информацию, решил что должен передаваться неизменяемый кортеж. Убрал скобки и запятую, все отлично работает

Comment: На самом деле кортеж создаёт сама запятая. Даже можно без скобок. Просто со скобками как-то нагляднее что-ли. Скобки без запятой - это обычные скобки группирующие выражения (как в арифметических операциях). Если распечатаете `markup`, то увидите, что скобки оттуда пропадают. А если добавите запятую, но не поставите скобок, то скобки там сами возникнут. :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
_dict = {
    'x1[0]': ['aaa', '000'],
    'x1[1]': ['bbb', '111'],
    'x1[2]': ['ccc', '222'],
    'x1[3]': ['ddd', '333'],
    'x1[4]': ['eee', '444'],
}
markup = ([[Button(val, query=k, same_peer=True) for val in _dict[k]] for k in _dict])
```